# Why does my direct reference of an array index show one address, but incremental reference shows another?

Tags: for-loop, pointers, memory, arduino-c++

My problem is when I directly reference an array's index I get one address, but get a different address when I reference it through a for loop.  The address is the same for zero index, but differ after that.  I am in the Arduino IDE using a Nano.

Code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("\nSerial connected.");

  
  int luckyNumbers[5] = {2, 5, 9, 7, 3};
  Serial.println("\nint luckyNumbers[5] = {2, 5, 9, 7, 3}\n");

  Serial.println("Direct reference...");
  Serial.print("luckyNumbers[0] = ");
  Serial.println(long(&luckyNumbers[0]));
  Serial.print("luckyNumbers[1] = ");
  Serial.println(long(&luckyNumbers[1]));
  Serial.print("luckyNumbers[2] = ");
  Serial.println(long(&luckyNumbers[2]));
  Serial.print("luckyNumbers[3] = ");
  Serial.println(long(&luckyNumbers[3]));
  Serial.print("luckyNumbers[4] = ");
  Serial.println(long(&luckyNumbers[4]));


  Serial.println("\n Now the for loop...");

  for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Serial.print(" i = ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" @ memory address ");
    Serial.println(long(&luckyNumbers + i));
  }
}

void loop() {
  //Do nothing.  Just.... don't.
}
```

Serial Console reads:

```
Serial connected.

int luckyNumbers[5] = {2, 5, 9, 7, 3}

Direct reference...
luckyNumbers[0] = 2290
luckyNumbers[1] = 2292
luckyNumbers[2] = 2294
luckyNumbers[3] = 2296
luckyNumbers[4] = 2298

 Now the for loop...
 i = 0 @ memory address 2290
 i = 1 @ memory address 2300
 i = 2 @ memory address 2310
 i = 3 @ memory address 2320
 i = 4 @ memory address 2330
```

I have been following CodeBeauty's course on pointers.  It is pretty fantastic and to the point.  Of course, she is using c++ and I am using a wrapped c++.  While I expected there to be some differences in code because of this, some of which you can see in how I convert the address datatype to print to the serial monitor, I wonder if the differences extend to how I am using the for loop to collect the addresses.[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsS-ZiYOWy4&list=PL43pGnjiVwgSSRlwfahAuIqoJ8TfDIlHq&index=4) is the video I am modeling my code from.

I expected to see memory addresses be equal to each other for both direct and incremental references.

Thank you in advance for taking time for my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct syntax.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 Serial.print(" i = ");
 Serial.print(i);
 Serial.print(" @ memory address ");
 int address = long((&luckyNumbers[i]));
 Serial.println(address);
}
```